# which sound format is best for cocos2d game project?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

i am new in cocos2d and facing hard time to find the best file format which is supported in cocos2d ?
and can i use ogg file format if Yes then please any link how to use it is cocos2d

Comment: www.google.com gave me the answer straight away using "iphone audio formats"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file that are supported in iPhone but for me `.wav` files are better.

Answer (score 3):

No ogg on iOS. Here's the AVAudioPlayer [supported audio formats list](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW33).

You also have to differentiate between background audio (streaming audio) and audio effects. For the former you should use mp3 and play only one mp3 at a time because the iOS devices can only decode one mp3 at a time using hardware. Additional mp3 are decoded with the CPU.

For audio effects uncompressed .caf and .wav files are standard. You want them to be 16-bit, mono and using a sample rate of 11, 22 or 44 kHz depending on the quality you need. Personally I would default to 22 kHz.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to convert audio to best iOS formate: [Click HERE](http://gamua.com/blog/2010/06/sound-on-ios-best-practices/)

Open terminal and run this command:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 sound.wav
```